# Passing parameters to click() & bind() event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to pass few parameters to `click()` event in jQuery, I tried following but it's not working:

```
commentbtn.click(function(id, name){
    alert(id);
});
```

And also if we use bind then how we'll do that:

```
commentbtn.bind('click', function(id, name){
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: What are `id` and `name`. Where do you get them from? Are the values at the time of the click or something initialised at the time you're binding? How will click know what to pass into the function? It will always pass the event object and nothing else.

Comment: They are initialized, before binding the event.

Comment: Well then, as [david](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994527/passing-parameters-to-click-bind-event-in-jquery/3994552#3994552) suggested in his answer, you'll either have to keep them as top level variables or create a closure. `click` doesn't know what you want *want* to pass into the handler.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

see [event.data](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/)

```
commentbtn.bind('click', { id: '12', name: 'Chuck Norris' }, function(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    alert(data.id);
    alert(data.name);
});
```

If your data is initialized before binding the event, then simply capture those variables in a closure.

```
// assuming id and name are defined in this scope
commentBtn.click(function() {
    alert(id), alert(name);
});
```

Comment: The jQuery documentation for the .click() method indicates this ability but offers no example of how to use it.  But, if you look up 'event.data' [https://api.jquery.com/event.data/], there you find an example.

Also check out Event Object: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 19):

From where would you get these values?
If they're from the button itself, you could just do

```
commentbtn.click(function() {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

If they're a variable in the binding scope, you can access them from without

```
var id = 1;
commentbtn.click(function() {
   alert(id);
});
```

If they're a variable in the binding scope, that might *change* before the click is called, you'll need to create a new closure

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   $('#button'+i).click((function(id) {
      return function() {
         alert(id);
      };
   }(i)));
}
```

Comment: I was confused by the case that the variable is changed when click is called. Thank you for this one!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for the bind() method.

Use the click() method, do something like this:

```
commentbtn.click({id: 10, name: "João"}, onClickCommentBtn);

function onClickCommentBtn(event)
{
  alert("Id=" + event.data.id + ", Name = " + event.data.name);
}
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
commentbtn.click({id: 10, name: "João"},  function (event) {
  alert("Id=" + event.data.id + ", Nome = " + event.data.name);
});
```

It will show an alert box with the following infos:

```
Id = 10, Name = João
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var someParam = xxxxxxx;

commentbtn.click(function(){

    alert(someParam );
});
```

Comment: I want to pass them within the event.

Comment: @Prashant: Can you give an example for that?

Comment: @Prashant - you can't just 'add' more params to your callback! jQuery won't know where to get the values from...