# Adding parameters to bind()

Tags: jquery, parameters, bind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing parameters to click() & bind() event in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994527/passing-parameters-to-click-bind-event-in-jquery)

I have this code,

```
clickcount = 0;

   function filter() {

            $(this).siblings().unbind('click', filter);
            $(this).siblings().css({opacity: '0.3'}, 800);
            clickcount++;

            if(clickcount == 2){
                $(this).siblings().bind('click', filter);
                 $(this).siblings().css({opacity: '1'}, 800);
                 clickcount =0;
            }


   }

        $('a.one').bind('click', filter);
        $('a.two').bind('click', filter);
        $('a.three').bind('click', filter);
```

What I want to do is, pass parameters to the 'filter' function, so I can dynamically pass data.

for instance this is how i'd do it in PHP :-

```
function test(var) { 
    return $var;
}

echo test('this is a variable');
```

how can I get a similar result using bind?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [`bind()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind), the second parameter of `bind()` can be an arbitrary map of data, which can be accessed inside the event handler using `event.data`

```
function filter(e) {
         // e.data.foo; etc

         $(this).siblings().unbind('click', filter);
         $(this).siblings().css({opacity: '0.3'}, 800);
         clickcount++;

         if(clickcount == 2){
              $(this).siblings().bind('click', filter);
              $(this).siblings().css({opacity: '1'}, 800);
              clickcount =0;
         }
}

$('a.one').bind('click', {
    blah: 1,
    foo: 2
}, filter);
```

Alternately, you can do;

```
$('a.one').bind('click', buildFilter(1, 2, 3));

function buildFilter(argA, argB, argC) {
  return function (e) {
    // Use argA, argB and argC

    $(this).siblings().unbind('click', filter);
    $(this).siblings().css({opacity: '0.3'}, 800);
    clickcount++;

    if(clickcount == 2){
      $(this).siblings().bind('click', filter);
      $(this).siblings().css({opacity: '1'}, 800);
      clickcount =0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this

```
$('a.one').bind('click', function () {
    filter(aaa, bbb); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Passing Event Data on [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) documentation:

```
.bind( eventType [, eventData], handler(eventObject) )
```

Example:

```
var message = 'Spoon!';
$('#foo').bind('click', {msg: message}, function(event) {
  alert(event.data.msg);
});
```

You can do this way:

```
commentbtn.bind('click', { id: '12', name: 'Chuck Norris' }, function(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    alert(data.id);
    alert(data.name);
});
```

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994527/passing-parameters-to-click-bind-event-in-jquery) that already available on Sstackoverflow for details.

```
$(this).siblings().bind('click',{id:1, cost:20}, filter);

function filter(event)
{
alert(event.data.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the event data to the function calls

```
$('a.one').bind('click', {msg: message}, filter);
```

Then in your filter function, you can retrieve the event data by doing event.data.msg

```
function filter () {
  ....
  alert(event.data.msg);
}
```

Check out the jquery bind documentation on Bind Event Data

http://api.jquery.com/bind/#passing-event-data