# angular directive - scope undefined inside function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I can't seem to reach the link function scope variable from inside a function in my directive. The "elem" variable is defined, but the scope isn't. Why is that??

Here's my directive:

```js
function contextMenu($document){
  return {
    scope: {
      target: '=',
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      elem.bind('contextmenu',handleRightClick);
      function handleRightClick(event) {
        // do something with scope (scope is undefined)
      }
    }
  }
};
```

How can I user the scope variable?

Thanks!

Uri

**EDIT1**:

I found I can use this to pass the scope to the function:
[Passing parameters to click() & bind() event in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994527/passing-parameters-to-click-bind-event-in-jquery), but this still doesn't explain why the scope variable is undefined.

**EDIT2:**

For completeness sake, this is how my directive is set up:

app.js

```
angular
  .module('myModule', [])
  .directive('contextMenu', ['$document', components.contextMenu])
```

and in the html:

```html
<div context-menu target="testObject">
```

Comment: Is there a reason why u r not using `ng-click`?

Comment: scope should be accessible. Do a console log of scope and check. Giving breakpoint inside function and verifying for scope might be undefined.

Comment: I've checked, it's undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the directive correctly. Since you didn't include the use of the directive in your template, I hope you used it something like this:

```
    <div context-menu target="something"></div>
```

Then I am confused about the setup of your directive. Try this:

```
    MyDirectiveModule.directive('contextMenu', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                target: '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, element){
                console.log(scope);
                // don't use $scope!
            }
        };
    });
```

Make sure to use `scope` instead of `$scope` in the `link:` part.

Comment: Thanks, I added the directive setup code. And, yes, i'm using scope and not $scope.

Comment: can you make a plunkr?

Comment: I tried recreating in a plunkr but it won't re create. The actual directive is nested inside some other directives in a bit of a complicated structure. Anyway, thanks for the help, if i'll manage to recreate i'll update the question.

Comment: Okay, maybe the complicated setup was the problem then? Good luck to you!